# Inserting JavaScript code for today's date in a textarea tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert today's date into a text area tag. Is it possible to do this? This is part of a response form. In the past we have entered today's date manually. However here it just turns my JS code to text. Thank you.

```
<i><b>Response:</b></i><br><textarea cols=65 rows=10 name="feedback" wrap="hard" tabindex="12" >
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date()
document.write(d.getMonth() + 1)
document.write("/")
document.write(d.getDate())
document.write("/")
document.write(d.getFullYear())
</script>

CURRENT DATE 
Response text.................
</textarea><br><br>
```

Comment: place the `<script>` ... `</script>` above the rest of your code

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I want the current date to be in the text area right above the response text. I would like the Current date to be text as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LV7eF/)

```
<textarea></textarea>

<script>

  var d = new Date(),
      month = d.getMonth() + 1,
      date = d.getDate(),
      year = d.getFullYear(),
      area = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];

  area.value = month +"/"+ date +"/"+ year;

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works but it gets rid of the rest of my Response Text and only populates the text area with the date.

Comment: Yes that will work great! Thanks. I just hit Enter a couple times after the start <textarea> tag so that the text ends up 2 lines down from the date.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you mean:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date()
    document.write(d.getMonth() + 1)
    document.write("/")
    document.write(d.getDate())
    document.write("/")
    document.write(d.getFullYear())
</script>

<i><b>Response:</b></i><br><textarea cols=65 rows=10 name="feedback" wrap="hard" tabindex="12" >


    Response text.................
</textarea><br><br>
```

It will output 5/16/2014 Response: and then the textarea which is empty (except for the Reponse text............................)